# How can I zip/compress a symlink?

Tags: linux, compression, symlink

Is it possible and how can I zip a symlink from a linux shell?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can store symlinks as symlinks (as opposed to a copy of the file/directory they point to) using the `--symlinks` or `-y` parameters of the `zip` program.

Assuming `foo` is a directory containing symlinks:

```
zip --symlinks -r foo.zip foo/
# or
zip -y -r foo.zip foo/
```

Which of the flags to use depends on your version of `zip`; more current versions may support both. Check `zip --help` or `man zip` to find the correct one for your situation.

Rar equivalent:

```
rar a -ol foo.rar foo/
```

`tar` stores them as is by default.

```
tar czpvf foo.tgz foo/
```

Note that the symlink occupies almost no disk space by itself (just an inode). It's just a kind of pointer in the filesystem, as you probably know.

Comment: i can't use tar, but the --symlinks is not working with zip. are you sure it's the default zip package?

Comment: Which distribution you've got? `Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license. Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008).` Can you use rar instead? See added example.

Comment: Copyright (c) 1990-2006 Info-ZIP.  All rights reserved. This is Zip 2.32  probably because of this. i will try rar

Comment: Splitting hairs, but technically the symlink does occupy disk space, consuming an inode.

Comment: True that. Actually from what I read in the past they were even more like regular files containing the path to the pointed file/directory. Now they're just a special kind of inode if I remember correctly.

Comment: what about 7z in windows?

Answer (score 13):

On RHEL 5, we have

```
$ zip -h
Copyright (C) 1990-2005 Info-ZIP
Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
Zip 2.31 (March 8th 2005). Usage:
zip [-options] [-b path] [-t mmddyyyy] [-n suffixes] [zipfile list] [-xi list]
(snip)
  -y   store symbolic links as the link instead of the referenced file
```

Comment: Same on OpenSUSE Leap. So it's indeed `zip -y -r foo.zip foo/`.