# How to create .zip archive containing preserved symlinks (shortcuts) in Windows (CLI)

Tags: windows, powershell, symlink, shortcut, zip

How can I create a `.zip` compressed archive in Windows from the command-line that preserves symlinks?

I'm trying to create `.zip` file in PowerShell that includes a relative symlink from one file to another file in that archive, but I either encounter an error or the shortcut turns into a non-symlink file after extraction.

```
mkdir test
cd test
echo 'foo' > bar
cmd /C mklink bar_link bar
cd ..
Compress-Archive -DestinationPath test.zip -Path test
```

What are the commands I should use to create a `.zip` file from a directory that contains a relative symlink to a file in the directory to be archived?

Comment: I don't think the zip file format supports symlinks.

Comment: my understanding is that symlinks and hardlinks are _filesystem_ things ... and i know of no archive format that supports anything more complex than directory structure.

Comment: Really? `tar` preserves symlinks..

Comment: Ok, well, if this is not possible with `.zip` what other native Windows archive formats support symlinks?

Comment: I thought as well that zip doesn't support symlinks an was about to comment that yesterday, but before I looked it up and at least the Unix version of zip [does support symlinks](https://serverfault.com/questions/265675/how-can-i-zip-compress-a-symlink). I don't know about the windows version though, since symlinks work different on NTFS.

Comment: You could try to use the win32 build of the linux zip tool.

Comment: I tested this. In linux, I created a zip archive with a symlink. It works fine. If you decompress it in linux, you get the symlink back again. But if you decompress this same .zip in Windows, then it dumps out the symlink as a file, not a symlink. So, it seems, Windows doesn't translate the symlink into a shortcut; it just outputs the symlink as the file to which it was linking-to.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield did you happen to find a solution eventually?

Comment: @Sz I'm sorry but I don't think this is possible. My use-case was for a compressed archive whoose contents was to be extracted onto a drive. So my solution was to add a `provision.sh` batch script to the `.zip` file that, when double-clicked in Windows, it creates the shortcut and deletes itself https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/blob/1a79dc07df39a2622ad32e042c21332a34cbf458/build/usb/usbDrive.sh#L206-L264

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows 10 (some 17*** build, end of 2017), the 'tar' command has been added natively. So now for preserving symlinks I would suggest something like:

```
tar -cvzf mybackup.tar.gz folder-to-backup
```

Then, after unpacking

```
tar -xvzf mybackup.tar.gz
```

the extracted folder folder-to-backup has all symlinks remaining.